# Little $o$ notation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose that $f:[0,\infty)\to f:[0,\infty)$ is continuous s.t. $f^{-1}$ is also continuous. For some increasing (positive) sequence $a_n$, $f(a_n)=o(n)$. Is it true that the last condition is equivalent to
$$
a_n=o(f^{-1}(n)) \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
without imposing additional assumptions on $f$ (except for mild ones)?

---

For example, $\eqref{1}$ holds for $f(x)=x^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what the domain of $f^{-1}$ should be, so I'm assuming you want $f^{-1}$ to be defined on $[0,\infty)$, that is, $f$ is bijective on $[0,\infty)$.

As a counterexample, consider $f(x)=e^{x}-1$ defined for $[0,\infty)$. Then $f^{-1}(x)=\ln(x+1)$ defined for $[0,\infty)$. Both functions are non-negative and continuous. Now consider the increasing sequence $a_n=\ln(\sqrt{n})$.
We have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f\left(a_n\right)}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}-1}{n}=0 $$
so $f(a_n)=o(n)$ holds. However,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{f^{-1}(n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\sqrt n\right)}{\ln(n+1)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac 12\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)}\right)=\frac 12 $$
so $a_n=o\left(f^{-1}(n)\right)$ doesn't hold.